# How to handle "Exception or null" cases uniformally in Java?

Tags: java

For example, I need to get a Foo object using getFoo() method:

```
Foo foo = getFoo();
```

After this, I want to handle the case that getFoo() didn't return a Foo object successfully. This in turn includes two cases:

1. getFoo() throws an exception.
2. The return result of getFoo() is null, empty String, 0, or whatever should be treated as "Empty result".

Ideally I would want getFoo() throw an exception instead of returning an empty result, but sometimes that may be a call to a method in another package which I don't own.

These are methods that I can think of:

#### 1. Duplicate handling code

```
Foo foo = null;
try {
    foo = getFoo();
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    logger.warn("blablabla");
    foo = defaultFoo;
    someOtherComplicatedStuff();
}
if (null == foo) {
    logger.warn("blablabla");
    foo = defaultFoo;
    someOtherComplicatedStuff();
}
```

This is definitely not a good idea.

#### 2. Move handling logic to an individual function

```
Foo foo = null;
try {
    foo = getFoo();
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    handleNullFoo(var1, var2, var3, var4);
}
if (null == foo) {
    handleNullFoo(var1, var2, var3, var4);
}
```

The problem is the logic may use a lot of local variables. Passing these variables to the external function doesn't make much sense. Worse, some of the variables may need to be modified during this process. I don't think modifying arguments in a function is a good practice, not to mention the issue it may cause if an argument is primitive typed.

#### 3. Throw a fake exception

```
Foo foo = null;
try {
    foo = getFoo();
    if (null == foo) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    logger.warn("blablabla");
    foo = defaultFoo;
    someOtherComplicatedStuff();
}
```

This is by far the cleanest way, but it is more like a kind of hack. It may not proper to throw a ResourceNotFoundException in a package the exception class doesn't belong to. It also decreases the readability of the code as people may not realize that the exception is handled inside the function.

So, what's your suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not handle exceptions when the interface contract is an exception and handle nulls when null is a possibility. I don't think a generic solution adds much value as with different libs come different exception types, so a generic way would have to deal with all kinds of scenarios or otherwise lose details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another alternative:

```
Foo foo = null;
try {
    foo = getFoo();
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    //TODO: log exception?
    foo = null;
}

if (null == foo) {
    logger.warn("blablabla");
    foo = defaultFoo;
    someOtherComplicatedStuff();
}
```

Note that the `foo = null;` in the `catch` clause is almost certainly unnecessary. It is only needed if there's some code after `foo = getFoo()` that can throw `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Comment: Not ideal, the content logger.warn would be different in practise: One time a resource not found, the othe rtime a different text

Comment: @AlexWien For this specific case, the OP stated the error handling code is identical.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Additionally you can store the exception in a variable in case you need to find out what happened.

Comment: Oh this is straightforward. Thank you as well as all who answered or commented on my question!

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
class WrappedFooFactory extends FooFactory {
  public foo tryGetFoo() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Foo foo = getFoo();
    if (null == foo) throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    return foo;
  }
}
```

and later just

```
Foo foo = null;
try {
    foo = tryGetFoo();
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    logger.warn("blablabla");
    foo = defaultFoo;
    someOtherComplicatedStuff();
}
```

Comment: See the original question: "Ideally I would want getFoo() throw an exception instead of returning an empty result, **but sometimes that may be a call to a method in another package which I don't own.**"

Comment: @AlexDiCarlo Which would make wrapping a bit more involved, but still a viable option. My point is to adapt the API (once), not the code using it (many times)

Comment: @Alex - I like this solution.  If the call is to a method in a package he doesn't own, and that package doesn't behave the way he wants it to, then simply write a wrapper that does.

Comment: Hah, here I am correcting you and I misunderstood your example (due to it not being actual Java syntax), I edited your post to add the `extends` keyword.

Comment: @AlexDiCarlo pls feel free to correct the syntax - I don't use Java on a day-to-day basis, but the problem exists the same way elsewhere

Comment: Agreed, and this is probably the cleanest solution, +1. (Or at least a variant of it, for example, it'd be slightly different if `FooFactory` was a `final` class)

Answer (score 2):

What about such alternative? It is more common and will be applicable for other similar cases.

1) Create static method:

```
public static <E> E wrapNulls(Callable<E> callable, E defaultValue) {
    E result = null;
    try {
        result = callable.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log exception
    }
    return result == null ? defaultValue : result;
}
```

2) Get your objects in such style:

```
    Foo foo = wrapNulls(new Callable<Foo>() {
        @Override
        public Foo call() throws Exception {
            return getFoo();
        }
    }, defaultValue);
```

**UPD:** For those, how fairly think, that this code is a bit verbose, I could suggest such enhancement:

3) create static class:

```
static abstract class C<E> implements Callable<E> {

    public abstract E c();

    @Override
    public E call() throws Exception {
        return c();
    }
}
```

and use it instead of `Callable` interface:

4)

```
Foo foo = wrapNulls(new C<Foo>() {public Foo c() { return getFoo(); }}, defValue);
```

Comment: Seems a bit verbose. However, in Java 8 with a lambda this would be a very nice solution.

Comment: @AlexDiCarlo Indeed. Furthermore, modern IDE-s (such Intellij IDEA) are able to represent such things in short code style (just for viewing, but very comfortable): `Foo foo = wrapNulls(() -> { return getFoo(); }, defaultFoo);` (it is only style of view, not exact code)

Comment: Yep, it's a neat trick, but it doesn't work so well in environments with code reviews, as most (all?) code review software does not have that functionality.

Comment: @AlexDiCarlo, I'm agree. In my update above you can see my suggestion about minimizing verbosity of such style.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3 is by far the worst! (Not the cleanest!)
Dont use Exceptions for flow control!

It depens a bit of the application but 1 is best because,
you can and usually will have two different log statements:

```
Foo foo = null;
try {
    foo = getFoo();
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    logger.warn("Foo: ", ex);
    foo = defaultFoo;
    someOtherComplicatedStuff();
}
if (null == foo) {
    logger.warn("Foo: Got unexpected null");
    foo = defaultFoo;
    someOtherComplicatedStuff();
}
```